# How to make typescript know my variable is not undefined anymore

Tags: typescript

Here is my case:

I am using a [Remix loader](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#loader-params) which get params from the URL but the params are defined as `string | undefined`

If the variable is `undefined` I would like to throw a [redirection](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#redirect)

```js
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }) => {
  const { myVar } = params; // myVar: string | undefined 
  definedOrRedirect(myVar, "/"); // Checks if undefined
  return fetchSomething(myVar); // myVar: string | undefined
};
```

Is there a way to make typescript know that if it didn't throw `myVar` is not undefined?

Comment: This can be accomplished with an *assertion function* like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx6bbw) but right now your code doesn't seem to be a [mre]; how does the compiler know what `params` is unless you annotate something?  Are you writing .ts or .js files?  If my link works for you then I'll write it up.  If not (e.g., you're type checking .js files where you need JSDoc stuff like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N53vMW)) then let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, it solved my issue. Do you know why it does not work with arrow function?

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work with arrow function"?  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDzrlW) work for you and solve your problem?  Ideally you'd provide a [mre] which shows exactly what the problem is in code.  So far I've been guessing.

Comment: I added more context into the post. I mean it simply does not have the same behavior than the function made with `function` keyword. Your example works on tsplay but on my side arrow function is not working but the with the `function` keyword it works.

I am using typescript 4.1.2 in my project. Can this be the reason?

Comment: Unfortunately this code is still not a [mre]. Ideally someone would be able to paste the code from the question here into a standalone IDE and see for themself what the problem is.  I can't make my IDE understand context, I have to figure out what modules to install and import and what types to declare.  My plan right now is to just answer the question as originally asked under the assumption that `{params}` is of type `{params: {myVar: string | undefined}}` and that I will write my own `throwIfUndefined` function which can be a function statement or arrow function.

Comment: If you can't get the arrow function version working, I don't know how to help unless I see the problem happen for myself in an IDE, especially because "not working" isn't specific enough for me to even hazard a guess at the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `throwIfUndefined` an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to narrow the type of its argument to something that does not include `undefined` in its domain.  An assertion function has an *assertion type predicate* of the form `asserts x is Y` as its return type, where `x` is the name of one of the function's parameters, and `Y` is the subtype of `typeof X` that we narrow `x` to assuming the function returns successfully.  Assertion functions cannot return a defined value; they are basically `void`-returning functions.

For `throwIfUndefined`, here's the normal way to do it, as a function statement:

```
function throwIfUndefined<T>(x: T | undefined): asserts x is T {
    if (typeof x === "undefined") throw new Error("OH NOEZ");
}
```

You can also write it as an arrow function, although you need to explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the variable with its type for the control flow analysis to happen correctly:

```
const throwIfUndefined: <T, >(x: T | undefined) => asserts x is T = x => {
    if (typeof x === "undefined") throw new Error("OH NOEZ");
}
```

Either way should work:

```
const Index = ({ params }: { params: { myVar: string | undefined } }) => {
    const { myVar } = params // myVar: string | undefined
    // myVar.toUpperCase // <-- error, Object is possibly 'undefined'
    throwIfUndefined(myVar);
    return myVar.toUpperCase() // no error now
}

try {
    console.log(Index({
        params: {
            myVar: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "hello" : undefined
        }
    })) // 50% "HELLO" 
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // 50% "OH NOEZ"
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAxArseAXAlge2AGUsQsJJgskBvAWACgkmkAzDbfYJLACwCc8AdwCSLAKrAAJhBY5gESQB4AKgD4AFAA8AXEmVIAPkgzTZ8yQEpdIKFAh8sUJJqQ4n+uo2becLJOqwATxgIPD8XAF4opAAiExk5BRiLbn4hJHlBJABRPgE+dRiAeQAJJAA5IuyALWSAbgZvAF8GVq8meAIoKmEpCEj-aiQ4PnAnJt0hkbHJpDBAgDUQPl1uvjkAc0NjPrMFJCaDlIjVGkbvZk7gbpo5xeWDpAjh5bGkAHp3u6WVpDXN7bxPaSc4XD5feY-AB0WDwYhgIT4AGEbMhPkhFABaTFIez5AA0SCKACMAFYQbCuJwwPC2HDEgA2gSQAHIgYlJCzQRdeAIROJdhz1JDlhYGu0LnwIFg0HwuCK+DC4Qj7Ci7OoUujgHhcXk8HwMkJuS16NysHxmZ4wR0ungGRAoQy8Bt1L1pJp1Fbrd5pmAoJNud7vArdABZUg8KGjKR4MAajFIAAMUIArEgAPyxHgQBlOmJIXTs8yB60m71NCyar4pxMAUliJWyABkm0V88akPBSPAeP4ICkvWCrlA7Q6nS7+3VwUga-XimVKjUYsa2ia2qBILAEMgAIJ6wToTC4AhnCXDqi8oSiCSmDm6FSEjQ6PSAwXmY6nGx2BxOFxuF-PJEpyDhcvj+EEIRhM4TzRHEb5JCkl5ZJkOR6gU84VFUtRiiuppnl0PR9AMnovKMfoHLMvr+rcIZ-OaAJGEW+yHBWTzASWNrXFQQwKo8zxUdOtH-MAWyMfBIISt46IKkq8KImqaJfFiOJ4vqhIkuSlL-jSdKMsybLiVyknMEh17icK9x8DhxlMFKMpyt8yyySqyKovGWo6qpBraoIuFmhap7esOo6Os6rpEZ6HEXFRAY2UGtHhrwUYgDGcYpIoSaphmWY5nmBY7LexZxc0UUVlWM51g2zatu2EqHF2WA9n2A5RcF9qhROYrTrOsSlJhS5+fQJpAA)

Answer (score 0):

You could skip `definedOrRedirect` and use an explicit check:

```py
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }) => {
  const { myVar } = params; // myVar: string | undefined 
  if (myVar == undefined) {
    return redirect("/");
  }
  return fetchSomething(myVar); // myVar: string
}
```

Or you could keep `definedOrRedirect` and declare it with an assertion as **jcalz** suggests:

```py
function definedOrRedirect(variable, path): asserts variable is string
{
  if (variable == undefined) {
    return redirect(path);
  }
}

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ params }) => {
  const { myVar } = params; // myVar: string | undefined 
  definedOrRedirect(myVar, "/");
  return fetchSomething(myVar); // myVar: string
}
```